# Python turtle tracer function isn't working

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I tried to use the tracer function to ignore animation to draw the shape quicker. This has worked for me in the past but now after using it it doesn't work. When I put the tracer line in the program does't draw anything; when I take it out it works, but very slowly which is why I wanted to take out animation.
Is this function still valid and I am using it wrong or is there a new funcion in it's place> Any recommendations?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import turtle
import random
import time
turtle.tracer(False)

turtle.title("Trippy Shape")
for i in range(360):
    turtle.circle(200)
    turtle.left(1)
```

Comment: Well of course it's not drawing anything. You told it not to draw anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you turn the tracer off, generally you won't see any drawing until you turn the tracer back on again or send an `update()` method to the screen.  (There are a few turtle operations that will trigger an `update()` all by themselves.)

```
import turtle

turtle.title("Trippy Shape")

turtle.tracer(False)

for i in range(360):
    turtle.circle(200)
    turtle.left(1)

turtle.tracer(True)

turtle.mainloop()
```